# Vba loop through all open workbook and comparing those workbook name with some value and do some operations

Tags: vba, excel

The code is giving me an error in the line `'**ERROR HERE`

I have several workbooks open which names are dynamic, Each workbook has a worksheet named "CC". I want to compare the value of D column with that workbook name in "CC" worksheet in all open workbooks and if that workbook name is not equal to column D value of worksheet CC then remove those rows from worksheet CC.

```
Sub filter()
    Dim wbs As Workbooks
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wbs = Application.Workbooks

    For Each wb In wbs
    For j = lastRowy(Worksheets("CC")) To 1 Step -1
        If wb.Name <> wb.Worksheets("CC").Cells(j, "D").Value Then '**ERROR HERE
            Rows(j).Delete
        End If
        Next j
    Next wb         
End Sub

Function lastRowy(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    lastRowy = sh.Cells.Find(what:="*", _
        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting? Also you haven't qualified the Worksheet reference here: `lastRowy(Worksheets("CC"))`. Change it to `lastRowy(wb.Worksheets("CC")) `

Comment: I have done so but It gives me Run Time error 9 Subscript out of range

Comment: So you probably have a workbook open which doesn't have a "CC" worksheet?

Comment: Thanks, Now Error has been removed, but the code is not giving any output. Output should be removal of all rows of all workbooks from CC worksheets which D column having different value from respective file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I've made sure your references are fully qualified and also some added  logic, see the comments for details.

```
Sub filter()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("CC")
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then 'check that worksheet exists
            lastRow = lastRowy(ws)
            If lastRow > 1 Then 'check that sheet has more than just headers
                For j = lastRow To 2 Step -1
                    If wb.Name <> ws.Cells(j, "D").Value Then
                        ws.Rows(j).Delete
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        End If
    Next wb
End Sub

Function lastRowy(sh As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = sh.Cells.Find(what:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'if Find didn't find anything then it would have returned rng = Nothing
    lastRowy = rng.Row
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, Just one more thing don't want to remove header row means row 1  so how can I exclude row 1 from comparison

Comment: @yashikavaish Updated. Just needed to edit the `If lastRow...` and `For j = lastRow...` lines to exclude row 1